# Building E-Bike system

Tags: batteries, brushless-dc-motor

I have a very simple question, I want to learn how to build E-bike (Battery / Controller / BLDC)
I want to understand first the system model and what's needed to be learned to build one.
I searched google but i didn't something clear about that.

Would you please help me .

Thanks in advance

Comment: what did you find? ... what did you not understand?

Comment: It's not about what I dont understand, it's about knowing what's needed , what are the parameters of the system.

Comment: Also would u please tell me what's the best bldc motor (parameters) used in electric bikes ? The average motors ? So I can determine the used current

Comment: There is no best motor. And you don't consider the motor until you have decided on the current already, from power requirements and your choice of battery voltage.

Comment: Ok this os good , from where can I read and learn these things ? Using the battery / power module etc...

Comment: Try looking on google and youtube

Comment: @user3093189 New programming students asked me about writing games. Of course, they wanted to know how to write a ***modern*** MMO in full 3D that's competitive, too. And they didn't even know how to code, yet. Seriously!?>? Sure, they had motivation. That's needed. But what they didn't understand and could not understand was just how many different disciplines they'd have to master to get to where they could even begin to see light at the end of the tunnel. You sound like that, here, to me. Powerful motives, no skills. Recommendation? Take the first step and then keep pushing a long time.

Comment: @jonk : I agree with you about what u have said, it's not a simple thing to build E-bike system. I know that very well. because of that my question is not i want to build an E-Bike system , But it is i want to LEARN how to build an E-Bike system and understanding first the system modeling . So i asked the correct question which is for learning a new thing . and BTW iam an Embedded SW Safety Engineer. So i have some skills, I just want to learn the system. so i can build it

Comment: @user3093189 Ah. Thank you for correcting my impression. It's good that you are starting from somewhere. It just came across to me, differently. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, extremely broad, general questions are generally going to yield low-quality answers on Electronics StackExchange. But I think it is useful to step back and look at the big picture involved with making a system like this since it covers different engineering domains and specializations. It may also help you understand how much goes into this.

You'll need to start by coming up with product specifications for your E-bike, chiefly the maximum acceleration you'll want to obtain, the maximum weight of the design (including the rider). From there, you can calculate the power you'll need to accelerate the mass to the given speed (1/2 mv^2 crap), which will help you select your motor.

Once you've selected your motor, you can design the power bridge for it, which will be three half-bridge (half H-bridge) drivers — one to drive each of the three phases of your BLDC motor. For smaller loads, there are single-chip motor driver ICs that have an integrated power stage, but I'm fairly confident you'll be drawing enough power to necessitate building your bridge out of discrete FETs and using a gate driver IC to control those FETs.

Before selecting your microcontroller, you'll have to decide how to commutate it (trapezoidal or sinusoidal field-oriented control — FOC — or something more esoteric), and your rotor position sensing strategy (6-step Hall-effect, encoder, or sensorless with estimators).

In the simplest 6-step hall-sensor-based commutation method, you can get away with a very simple microcontroller (or even an off-the-shelf motor driver chip with built-in commutation), but for sensorless FOC, a microcontroller with a floating-point unit will make development easier.

Then you'll need to work on the battery side of things. Calculate your peak power output, desired battery life, and bus voltage. From there, select your Li-Ion cell arrangement, which will let you design the battery management system (charger and cell balancer) that go into the project.

There's a lot going on! Hope this helps you at least understand the complexity of a project like this.

Comment: thanks a lot for that great explanation, actually i learned about the BLDC and how to control it, and i also searched about IC that includes MCU and Half bridges drivers and i found . For the battery system i didn't start yet. but i what i want really and i don't find is the system specs of the E-bike, Do you know where i can find that ?

Comment: What do you mean by system specs? Give me an example of what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, any system has requirements, system / sw / hw requirements. And to understand any system you need the system requirements. Or of there is a book about the e-bike system . Thanks in advance

Comment: You, as the designer, come up with those system requirements based on the product you want to build. I don't know what you don't understand about that? An e-bike designed to propel a 250-lb person to 20 mph in 3 seconds requires a much more powerful motor and drive system than one designed for a 60-lb child to go 5 mph. Why do you think there would be one set of system requirements for every e-bike ever built? The system specifications are what distinguish competing products from each other. It's the bare minimum thing that you bring to the table that describes what you're trying to build.